# Are there banned words in New York standarized tests?

Tags: united-states, children, language

I just came across a random post on a random news blog saying that several words were banned from New York's standardized tests. This included common words, such as Christmas, dinosaurs, birthdays.

I really disbelieved of this so I made a quick search hoping to end up in nothing, but came across several non reliable sources with the same info, and [this post from The Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/answer-sheet/post/50-plus-banned-words-on-standardized-tests/2012/03/30/gIQANuqJkS_blog.html):

> You might expect a standardized test to avoid using profane words but, it turns out, other words are banned too and they may surprise you: dinosaur and Halloween, rock ‘n roll and rap music, just to name a few. (...)

I still have a rough time believing in this.

Is this true?

Comment: That doesn't look like *The* Washington Post, but rather *a* Washington Post *blog*, linking to another random-looking page ("silive.com").

Comment: I've removed the second question because nobody is claiming beneficial effects

Comment: I once heard of "gun" being removed from a list of words to spell. Can't remember where or when though.

Comment: @Sklivvz, my bad. The original sources I found claimed that this was done in order to prevent "traumatizing children", but this new sources do not claim so.

Comment: Without being able to provide any references I would suggest that questions that revolve around cultural ideas and rituals (like "Christmas") would represent a possible source of bias against immigrants and people from minority cultural traditions, making them problematic from the point of view of getting a good measurement of achievement.

Comment: @dmckee I did think so, but part of the test itself could account for social immersion, a good test for education results. I find it hard to believe that children in Ney York, be of any culture that they follow, have not heard about Christmas or birthdays. I don't mean they are fully involved in their history, but I would expect _anyone_ to be able to have a conversation and name them. Why would a test be different? (Just personal opinion here.)

Comment: @Alpha The thing is that courts have been very suspicious of these issues since the civil rights movement and bureaucracies can be very gun-shy about lawsuits. Cheaper and safer to not fight the lawsuit in the first place, *even* if it is one that you can win.

Comment: @dmckee I see your point, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Alpha If I'm a strict Muslim, I might not have told my kids anything helpful about Christmas. And plenty of Christian kids probably know nothing about Ramadan.

Comment: I'd say there's good reason for leaving words that might set off PTSD triggers out of spelling tests, @AndrewGrimm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is a real list of *guidelines* sent to test-makers by the New York Department of Education - a practice in common with other US states, but differing in its extent.

It was covered by [CBS in New York](http://newyork.cbslocal.com/2012/03/26/war-on-words-nyc-dept-of-education-wants-50-forbidden-words-removed-from-standardized-tests/). While the video attached to this page includes a lot of speculation, it includes a door-stop interview with an official, Schools' Chancellor Dennis Walcott, that confirms the nature of the list.